# Restore normal up and down arrow operation in chrome? 

Tags: google-chrome

How can I restore normal functionality when using www.google.com and Chrome,

So up and down arrows don't go through links on the page and so they just move the page up and down, so they just scroll the page normally smoothly. The new functionality, it jump-scrolls the page when it hits the bottom of the screen it's a bit like a page down. I don't want that. I just want the behavior as with any normal website with chrome,  Other than www.google.com where up/down arrows scroll the page up and down normally.

Comment: The only official way to do that is to turn off Google Instant.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex That's pretty good, you can post that as an answer and i'll accept it unless something better comes along.